# VerneMQ not kicking client with revoked certificate

Tags: mqtt, mqtt-vernemq

I have setup VerneMQ to pull CRL (Certificate Revocation List) from Vault. Followingis my setup manifest.

```
kind: ConfigMap
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: vernemq-refresh-crl
  namespace: backend
  labels:
    app: vernemq
data:
  pull_crl.sh: |
    #!/usr/bin/env sh
    if ! apk info | grep ^curl ; then apk update && apk add curl; fi
    while true
    do
      echo $(date)
      curl -w "\n" --header "X-Vault-Token: $VAULT_TOKEN" http://vault.backend.svc.cluster.local:8200/v1/my-ca/crl/pem > /tmp/shared/ca.crl
      sleep $SLEEP_INTERVAL
    done

---

apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: vernemq
  namespace: backend
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: vernemq
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: vernemq
    spec:
      serviceAccountName: vernemq
      containers:
        - name: vernemq
          image: vernemq/vernemq:1.12.3
          ports:
            - name: mqtt
              containerPort: 1883
            - name: mqtts
              containerPort: 8883
            - name: mqtt-ws
              containerPort: 8080
            - name: epmd
              containerPort: 4369
            - name: vmq
              containerPort: 44053
            - name: metrics
              containerPort: 8888
          env:
            - name: DOCKER_VERNEMQ_ACCEPT_EULA
              value: "yes"
            - name: MY_POD_NAME
              value: "vernemq"
            - name: DOCKER_VERNEMQ_KUBERNETES_NAMESPACE
              valueFrom:
                fieldRef:
                  fieldPath: metadata.namespace
            - name: DOCKER_VERNEMQ_KUBERNETES_APP_LABEL
              value: "vernemq"
            - name: DOCKER_VERNEMQ_LOG__CONSOLE__LEVEL
              value: "debug"
            - name: DOCKER_VERNEMQ_KUBERNETES_LABEL_SELECTOR
              value: "app=vernemq"
            - name: DOCKER_VERNEMQ_LISTENER__TCP__ALLOWED_PROTOCOL_VERSIONS
              value: "3,4,5"
            - name: DOCKER_VERNEMQ_LISTENER__SSL__ALLOWED_PROTOCOL_VERSIONS
              value: "3,4,5"
            - name: DOCKER_VERNEMQ_ALLOW_ANONYMOUS
              value: "on"
            - name: DOCKER_VERNEMQ_TOPIC_MAX_DEPTH
              value: "20"
            - name: DOCKER_VERNEMQ_KUBERNETES_INSECURE
              value: "1"
            - name: DOCKER_VERNEMQ_MAX_ONLINE_MESSAGES
              value: "-1"
            - name: DOCKER_VERNEMQ_MAX_OFFLINE_MESSAGES
              value: "-1"
            - name: DOCKER_VERNEMQ_MAX_INFLIGHT_MESSAGES
              value: "0"
            - name: DOCKER_VERNEMQ_LISTENER__TCP__DEFAULT
              value: "0.0.0.0:1883"
            - name: DOCKER_VERNEMQ_LISTENER__SSL__DEFAULT
              value: "0.0.0.0:8883"
            - name: DOCKER_VERNEMQ_LISTENER__WS__DEFAULT
              value: "0.0.0.0:8080"
            - name: DOCKER_VERNEMQ_LISTENER__HTTP__METRICS
              value: "0.0.0.0:8888"
            - name: DOCKER_VERNEMQ_LISTENER__HTTP__DEFAULT
              value: "0.0.0.0:8888"
            - name: DOCKER_VERNEMQ_LISTENER__SSL__REQUIRE_CERTIFICATE
              value: "on"
            - name: DOCKER_VERNEMQ_LISTENER__SSL__USE_IDENTITY_AS_USERNAME
              value: "on"
            - name: DOCKER_VERNEMQ_LISTENER__SSL__CAFILE
              value: "/vernemq/cert/ca.crt"
            - name: DOCKER_VERNEMQ_LISTENER__SSL__CERTFILE
              value: "/vernemq/cert/server.crt"
            - name: DOCKER_VERNEMQ_LISTENER__SSL__KEYFILE
              value: "/vernemq/cert/server.key"
            - name: DOCKER_VERNEMQ_LISTENER__SSL__CRLFILE
              value: "/tmp/shared/ca.crl"
          volumeMounts:
            - name: cert
              mountPath: /vernemq/cert
              readOnly: true
            - name: acl
              mountPath: /vernemq/acl
              readOnly: true
            - name: tmp-shared
              mountPath: /tmp/shared
        - name: pull-crl
          image: alpine
          command: ["/bin/sh"]
          args: ["-c", "/script/pull_crl.sh"]
          env:
            - name: VAULT_TOKEN
              valueFrom:
                secretKeyRef:
                  name: vault
                  key: root-token
            - name: SLEEP_INTERVAL
              value: "300"
          volumeMounts:
            - name: pull-crl-sh
              mountPath: /script/pull_crl.sh
              subPath: pull_crl.sh
            - name: tmp-shared
              mountPath: /tmp/shared
      volumes:
        - name: cert
          secret:
            secretName: vernemq-cert
        - name: pull-crl-sh
          configMap:
            name: vernemq-refresh-crl
            defaultMode: 0744
        - name: tmp-shared
          emptyDir: {}
```

I do see serial number of revoked certificate in `/tmp/shared/ca.crl` but client using the revoked certificate is able to maintain already establish session with broker.

Is there a easy way to kick the client with revoked certificate

Comment: Are you sure vernmq will re-read the file when it changes with you needing to poke it (e.g. SIGHUP)

Comment: If vernmq doesn't reload CRL file, then is there a way to force vernmq for it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the administrative `disconnect` command with `sudo vmq-admin session disconnect --help`.

In general, it is a wrong assumption that adding a cert to the CRL will disrupt an existing connection. You have to couple that step with an administrative disconnect of the client.